# Why I'm Unable to create a Maven Project

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, maven

Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6

Getting this above Error.How to Proceed further?

[image]

Comment: Might I assume you've tried re-installing Maven?

Also, what does this have to do with Selenium?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your maven repository configuration is wrong.

Remove your maven repository first.

maven update (check forced option) > maven clean > maven install.